# AWS IAM Policy to allow full access to services, but only on the instances this user created

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I would like to write a policy for a new IAM user so that he can have a full access to AWS Services such as EC2, RDS, Cloud Front, S3, etc. However he should be only able to view (describe) and manage the instances/services that he launches. He can't see other existing/future instances/services created by other users.
This case happens in a company that wants to outsource some projects to an outsourced company. So the new IAM user is for giving access to the outsourced company to setup the staging & production environments in AWS that belongs to the company. How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Best Regards,

Mark

Comment: The describe* APIs don't support that kind of permission. You may be better off with multiple accounts (linked via consolidated billing)

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT there are no conditions on creator.

One obvious alternative is having a separated dependent and linked account with consolidated billing. You can find some detail in the third scenario of this paper

https://media.amazonwebservices.com/AWS_Setting_Up_Multiuser_Environments_Education.pdf

> [...] an administrator creates separate AWS accounts for each user who
>   needs a new AWS account. These accounts can optionally be linked
>   together and a single AWS account can be designated as the paying
>   account using consolidated billing, which provides a single bill for
>   multiple AWS accounts. The administrator then creates an IAM user in
>   each AWS account and applies an access control policy to each user.
>   Users are given access to the IAM user within their AWS account, but
>   do not have access to the root credentials of the AWS account.
>
> Users can log into the AWS Management Console with their IAM
>   credentials and then they can launch and access different AWS
>   services, subject to the access control policies applied to their
>   account. Users have direct control over the access credentials for
>   their resources and they can also share these resources  with other
>   users as necessary.